# How to test in scenario many methods calling one helper method

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, powermockito

For example here is my scenario:

```
function A() {
   C();
}

function B() {
   C();
}

function C() {
   if (someState > 0) then doSomething();
   else doSomethingElse();
}
```

I want to make all test case that coverage all code. Because `C()` has a condition so for testing `C()`, we need two testing method: `testC1()` and `testC2()`. So the total test is: `testA_C1()` `testA_C2()` `testB_C1()` `testB_C1()`. Number of testing methods will be increased dramatically when there are more conditions, and there are more methods that use same method `C()`

The problem here is: `C()` is not depend on any state of `A()` and `B()`, so in fact I think `C()` can be tested separately. So I think we can save a big amount of unit test.

My question is: How can I test in this scenario. I'm using `Powermock` for  Android Testing.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If as you said the `c()` doesn't depends on state of `a()` and `b()` then you can make [extract method object](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceMethodWithMethodObject.html)  refactoring and test it separately. In case if you use factory then you won't need PowerMock.

If `a()` and `b()` doesn't depends on `c()` result then the [suppress method](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/SuppressUnwantedBehavior) can be used.

If `a()` and `b()` depends on `c()` result, then you can create partially mock (by using spy) and mock the `c()`.

Comment: So we still test `A_C1()` `A_C2()` `B_C1()` `B_C2()` But use some methodologies you have mentioned for saving repeated code. right?

Comment: If code paths in `A()` and `B()` doesn't depend on `C()` then - no, you will test only `A`, `B`, `C_1, `C_2`.
I've create a [code examples](https://github.com/thekingnothing/stackoverflow/tree/master/q36482557) hot it can look like in different cases